# How to use a global forward (struts-config.xml) in Struts2 JSP?

Tags: jsp, struts2, struts-config, struts1, struts-tags

I am migrating a Struts1 web app to Struts2.  I have the following in my struts-config.xml file:

```
<global-forwards >
    <forward name="css" path="/common/css/app-global.css" />
</global-forwards>
```

In my JSP today (Struts 1), I have this call:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" id="default" type="text/css" href="<html:rewrite forward='css'/>" />
```

What is the equivalent way to do this in the JSP in Struts 2?  I tried `<s:url value="css">` but no luck.

I just want to point to the reference in global-forwards.  I'm sure it's something simple I'm overlooking.

**UPDATE:**  Listen, if there is a better way than using struts-config.xml (which I'm wondering if that should even be used in Struts 2), then by all means, set me straight.  I just didn't know if using the actual path was superior/inferior to using the specified forward name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for some global forward mapping or whatever. Just use `<s:url>` tag with `value` attribute.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" id="default" type="text/css" 
      href="<s:url value='/common/css/app-global.css'/>" />
```

Comment: Excellent!  Just what the doctor ordered...much appreciated, sir!